# return custom object from stored procedure executed in EntityFramework, can't see object results

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure using Entity Framework. I've tried the below and it returns the correct amount of rows, but when I look at the data in the debug window, it just shows my TYPE, it won't let me drill into to see what the actual values are.

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@targetDate", filedate);
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<PositionSheetCompResults>("dbo.comparePositionSheet @targetDate", param1);
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

here are the results it SHOULD return
[image]

here is the class

```
    public class PositionSheetCompResults
{
    public string AcctNum { get; set; }
```

Comment: What does `PositionSheetCompResults` look like? What data does the proc return?

Comment: it returns about 6 different columns... strings... and decimal datatypes

Comment: [edit] that into the question, with actual code!

Comment: I edited @DavidG

Comment: Don't forget the `PositionSheetCompResults` class.

Comment: so thank you.  you pointed out a dumb mistake on my part of where I forgot to fully create the class PositionSheetCompResults...

Answer (score 0):

You should write `ToList<PositionSheetCompResults>();`

`var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<PositionSheetCompResults>("dbo.comparePositionSheet @targetDate", param1).ToList<PositionSheetCompResults>();`